# How to solve $2^x+e^x=400$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This should be pretty easy, I know. It involves logs, but then there's this 400. So logs of what? And since $2^x$ and $e^x$ are different things, I can't substitute the values and solve as a second degree equation. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You are better than me if you say this should be pretty easy.

Comment: I don't think this will have a "clean" solution

Comment: @Chinny84 I said it should be easy, I'm not saying it is easy for me.

Comment: you can solve this numerically; there is nothing easy about it. $$  x \approx 5.8372 $$

Comment: @zasan: Your take-home lesson here is that just because a problem is simple to _state_ doesn't mean it is _easy_ to solve or even has a simple-looking solution. So don't call a problem easy unless you're sure it actually is.

Comment: An interesting point is that you can use the intermediate value theorem, and the mean value theorem(basically looking at the derivatives), to show that there exist a solution, and that the solution is unique. When you then find a solution numerically as explained in other answers, you know that it is unique.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm sorry. I'm in prep school. My instructor wouldn't give us something extremely difficult (also, he's never solved a similar problem in class). So yeah, I thought it was something easy to solve. But thanks for clarifying why everyone seemed so upset about this.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: As an extreme example, consider Fermat's Last Theorem.  Easy to state, but took 358 years to prove.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$e^x(1+(\frac{2}{e})^x)=400$$
take the log
$$x+\log(1+(\frac{2}{e})^x)=\log 400$$
$$x=\log \frac{400}{1+(\frac{2}{e})^x}$$

then use Fixed-point Iteration Method by selecting $x=1$ to get new value of $x=5.4400198...$
repeat this many times to get 
$$x=5.837229692...$$

Comment: While this is true, I don't see how it leads to an answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think the idea is that it can be somewhat easier to find a numerical solution to that equation.

Comment: @RossMillikan see the editing in my answer

Comment: Why the downvote????!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, no! I don't remember doing this. I didn't know I could do this (I'm new to this site, I thought I didn't have permission). I think I tried upvoting and ended up downvoting? Your answer was just what I was looking for. I was about to thank you and then I saw it. I just fixed it. Sorry. And thank you very much!

Comment: @zasan: Relax, it can't possibly have been you -- you don't have enough points to be _able_ to downvote yet.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see how you will get an algebraic solution.  To get a numeric one, you can just ask [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex%2Be%5Ex%3D400) and find $x \approx 5.83723$  To find that yourself with a simple calculator, you can think that $2^x$ is probably small compared to $e^x$,  write the equation as $e^x=400-2^x, x=\log(400-2^x)$ and make it a fixed-point iteration:  $x_{i+1}=\log (400-2^{x_i})$, start with $x_0=0$ and iterate to convergence. I get convergence in Excel in 7 steps.

Comment: If you're talking about appealing to Banach's fixed point theorem, then I think that might be a bit beyond what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @AJY:  The theorem is required to show that the iteration will converge.  Fixed-point iteration is a nice way to find numeric results-you just put slowly varying terms on the right and hope that (or prove) that the derivative is less than $1$ in absolute value.  If it isn't you fly off to infinity, which is a clue to try something else.  Of course you can use bisection or Newton as well.

Comment: I was simply pointing out that not many (pre-)calculus classes will cover BFT. Newton or bisection would be much more likely.

Answer (score 5):

In general, equations such that $$f(x)=2^x+e^x-400$$ or more generally $$e^{ax}+e^{bx}=c$$ do not show explicit solutions and numerical methods should be used.

The case you post is interesting because we can immediately find an interval which contains the root; effectively we have $$2 \times 2^x <2^x+e^x<2\times e^x$$ since $e>2$. So, the solution of $f(x)=0$ will be such that $$\log (200) <x <\frac{\log (200)}{\log (2)}$$ For the solution, let us consider Newton method which, starting from a guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Because $e>2$ we can suspect that the solution will be closer to the left bound than to the right bound. So, let us use $x_0=\log(200)$ and start the method; it will generate the following iterates $$x_1=6.00516465176756$$ $$x_2=5.85018388717197$$ $$x_3=5.83731059720133$$ $$x_4=5.83722969482574$$ $$x_5=5.83722969165702$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant figures.

However, we could have done much better considering instead $$g(x)=\log \left(2^x+e^x\right)-\log (400)$$ which much more linear than $f(x)$ (if you plot both functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ over the range we defined, $g(x)$ really looks like a straight line while $f(x)$ is rather stiff). Using the same method and the same starting point, the iterates would be $$x_1=5.83913551659931$$ $$x_2=5.83722971355888$$ $$x_3=5.83722969165702$$

We still could do better if, instead of Newton method, we use Halley method. In such a case, the successive iterates would be $$x_1=5.83714334263199$$ $$x_2=5.83722969165702$$

**Edit**

Still more funny ! Taking into account the upper and lower bounds established at the very beginning, we know that $\big(\frac 2 e\big)^x$ will be a very small number. So, rewrite $$\log \left(2^x+e^x\right)=\log \left(e^x\left(1+\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x\right) \right)=x+\log \left(1+\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x\right) $$ and use the fact that, for small $y$, $\log(1+y)\approx y$. Replace $y$ by $\big(\frac 2 e\big)^x$ which makes $$g(x)\approx x+\Big(\frac 2 e\Big)^x-\log(400)$$ Just for your curiosity, the solution of  equation $x+a^x=b$ expresses in terms of Lambert function (you will learn it soon) $$x=b-\frac{W\left(a^b \log (a)\right)}{\log (a)}$$ Applied to your case it will then be $\approx 5.82402$ while $\log(200)\approx 5.29832$. So, we now have a much better starting point $x_0$ for any iterative method.

Amazing too : looking at $RIES$, the solution of the equation is very close to $$ 2^e-\frac{1+e}{5}\approx 5.83722962532611$$ $$\frac{1}{\log ^2(3 \phi )}+2 e\approx 5.83722968721501$$.

Comment: From $\log \left(2^x+e^x\right)=x+\log \left(1+\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^x\right)$ you can take a different bound that is $\ln 200 < x < \ln 200 + \ln2$, what is better that what you get in the beginning. Anyway an interval of $\ln 2$ is too much error

Comment: @Masacroso. You are totally right ! Thank you. And the funny is that this gives an initial value extremely close to $6$ !

Comment: I was thinking about some kind of recursion that implies some truncated series... but it seems hard. You can write everything as infinite series and add it up because all converges, then the series is equal to zero and from here maybe try some recursion or whatever :p

Comment: In such a case, why not $x_{n+1}=\log(400-2^{x_n})$ starting with $x_0=6$ ? It works fine. Add that as an answer. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

an algebraic solution doesn't exist, by a numerical method we get $$x\approx 5.8372296916570249573$$

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the equation as follows. We have:

$$2^x = \exp\left[\log(2^x)\right] = \exp\left[x\log(2)\right]= \exp(x)^{\log(2)}$$

The equation can thus be rewritten as:

$$y^{\log(2)} + y = 400$$

where $y = \exp(x)$. This is not an algebraic equation, but in some sense it's close to one. If you approximate $\log(2)$ by a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ and substitute $y = z^q$ then you get the algebraic equation

$$z^p + z^q = 400$$